# How to return null pointer for list member c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, nullpointerexception

I need to return pointer for a member in a list, and if the required member is not there I get a null pointer (or any other indication)

```
list<LINKS>::iterator find_link(list<LINKS> &link, char* ID)
{
    list<LINKS>::iterator link_index;
    LINKS link_i;

    link_index = link.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < link.size(), i++)
    {
        link_i = *link_index;

        if (!strcmp(link_i.ID, ID)) { return link_index; };

        link_index++;

    };
    cout << "Node outsession does not exist " << ID;
    return nullptr; // ERROR (nullptr is not the same type as list<LINKS>::iterator)
};
```

I added the error message (`cout << "Node outsession does not exist " << ID;`) to indicate if the link is not found, but I need to indicate that for the caller function.

How can I do that ?
Thanks

Comment: The canonical way to return a "not found" iterator would be to return `link.end();`.

Comment: But link.end() is still a valid pointer for the caller function. The caller will never notice that the link does not exist.

Comment: The caller will say `if(find_link(links, &ID) == links.end()) // error`

Comment: @Ammar The only valid use for an end iterator is to signal the end of a range, if whoever calls the function uses it for anything else that's their problem.

Comment: I don't think having a `std::list` of linked lists is the right idea. You do realize that `std::list` is itself a linked list?

Comment: You should know that `links.end()` does ***not*** point to any valid elements in the list. It points *past the end* of the list. It is as close to an `iterator` equivalent of a null pointer as you can probably get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nullptr` is not an iterator, so you can't return it in a function that returns an iterator value

`std::find(begin(), end(), value)` returns an iterator and returns `end()` if the value is not found.  To check it you say:

```
std::list<int> l;
...
auto found = std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), 6); // returns an std::list::iterator
if (found == l.end())
{
    std::cout << "Bogus!" << std::endl;
}
...
```

There are other examples in which the container find returns a value, and uses a special value for "not found"

```
std::string s = "go to the store";
auto found = s.find('x'); // returns a size_t index into the string
if (found == std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "Bogus!" << std::endl;
}
```

Returning `nullptr` would make sense if your function returned a pointer.  In that case, `nullptr` would be a reasonable sentinel value for not found.

Answer (score 1):

The normal accepted way to return 'value not found' when searching a list is to return an iterator pointing to the end of the list. In this case `link.end()`

This is exactly how the `std::find` algorithm from `<algorithm>` behaves.

In your calling function test the returned iterator as follows:

```
list<LINKS>::iterator itr = find_link(list, "Funyuns");
if( itr == list.end() ) {
   std::cout << "You are all out of Funyons :-(" << std::endl;
}
```